# "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, jsdom

Good afternoon, I started to deal with jsdom. Wrote a very simple function for clarity. Wrote a test using mocha, chai, and JSDOM.

All the "documents" in my `module.js` is hidden due to the fact that if I uncomment them, the error `"ReferenceError: document is not defined"` will appear. In theory, I already understand what it means. This error means that **in Node there is no window, document, etc**. But I don’t know how to solve this problem.

I would be grateful for any help.

[image]

[image]

*index.html:*

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="inputValue">
  <input type="text" id="outputValue">
  <button id="getResult">getResult</button>

  <script src="./module.js"></script>
</body>
```

*module.js*

```
//var input = document.getElementById("inputValue");
//var output = document.getElementById("outputValue");
//var button = document.getElementById("getResult").addEventListener('click', generateValue);

function generateValue(input, output){
    output.value = input.value * 5;
}

module.exports = {
    generateValue,
};
```

*tests.js*

```
    let object = require("../module.js");
const assert = require("chai").assert;
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

describe("generateValue", function() {
    let dom = null;
    before(async function() {
        dom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><head></head><body></body></html>')
    });

    it('Should return 25 when parameter 5', function() {
        const input = dom.window.document.createElement("input");
        input.id = "inputValue";
        const output = dom.window.document.createElement("input");
        output.id = "outputValue";
        dom.window.document.body.append(input);
        dom.window.document.body.append(output);
        input.value = 5;
        const expected = 25;

        object.generateValue(input, output);
        assert.equal(output.value, expected);
    });
});
```